# Airflow using SQL Server as the backend, but gets stuck during the initdb command:

Tags: airflow

This issue is exactly same as below, but the answer did not work for me.

[Airflow - Initiation of DB stuck in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922012/airflow-initiation-of-db-stuck-in-sql-server?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I am stuck with this issue for the past two days, Any help would be greatly appreciated...!

More details:

I am using docker to run airflow, While initiating airflow DB, it gets stuck in the below task for sometime.

```
DB: mssql+pymssql://sqlserver:***@10.10.18.10:1433/Test_airflow
[2020-03-13 09:51:10,556] {db.py:368} INFO - Creating tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl MSSQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> e3a246e0dc1, current schema
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade e3a246e0dc1 -> 1507a7289a2f, create is_encrypted
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1507a7289a2f -> 13eb55f81627, maintain history for compatibility with earlier migrations
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 13eb55f81627 -> 338e90f54d61, More logging into task_instance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 338e90f54d61 -> 52d714495f0, job_id indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 52d714495f0 -> 502898887f84, Adding extra to Log
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 502898887f84 -> 1b38cef5b76e, add dagrun
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1b38cef5b76e -> 2e541a1dcfed, task_duration
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e541a1dcfed -> 40e67319e3a9, dagrun_config
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 40e67319e3a9 -> 561833c1c74b, add password column to user
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 561833c1c74b -> 4446e08588, dagrun start end
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4446e08588 -> bbc73705a13e, Add notification_sent column to sla_miss
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bbc73705a13e -> bba5a7cfc896, Add a column to track the encryption state of the 'Extra' field in connection
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade bba5a7cfc896 -> 1968acfc09e3, add is_encrypted column to variable table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 1968acfc09e3 -> 2e82aab8ef20, rename user table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2e82aab8ef20 -> 211e584da130, add TI state index
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 211e584da130 -> 64de9cddf6c9, add task fails journal table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 64de9cddf6c9 -> f2ca10b85618, add dag_stats table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade f2ca10b85618 -> 4addfa1236f1, Add fractional seconds to mysql tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 4addfa1236f1 -> 8504051e801b, xcom dag task indices
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 8504051e801b -> 5e7d17757c7a, add pid field to TaskInstance
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 5e7d17757c7a -> 127d2bf2dfa7, Add dag_id/state index on dag_run table
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 127d2bf2dfa7 -> cc1e65623dc7, add max tries column to task instance
```

When i looked into MSSQL database and find the process creating two connections, one waiting and one locked by the other:

```
exec sp_who;

spid    ecid    status  loginame    hostname    blk dbname  cmd request_id
55  0   sleeping    sqlserver my_server   Test_airflow AWAITINGCOMMAND 0
56  0   suspended   sqlserver my_server   55  Test_airflow EXECUTE 0'
```

after 5 or 10 mins, i get the below logs in docker(creating tables & metadata task gets timeout error).

```
ERROR [airflow.utils.timeout.timeout] Process timed out, PID: 7
malloc(): unsorted double linked list corrupted
/entrypoint.sh: line 69:     7 Aborted                 airflow initdb
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:241: FutureWarning: The task_runner setting in [core] has the old default value of 'BashTaskRunner'. This value has been changed to 'StandardTaskRunner' in the running config, but please update your config before Apache Airflow 2.0.
  FutureWarning
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:631: DeprecationWarning: Specifying both AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and airflow_home in the config file is deprecated. Please use only the AIRFLOW_HOME environment variable and remove the config file entry.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)
[2020-03-13 13:19:24,141] {settings.py:253} INFO - settings.configure_orm(): Using pool settings. pool_size=0, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=15
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/pymssql.pyx", line 450, in pymssql.Cursor.execute
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1064, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1095, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1228, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1639, in _mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
  File "src/_mssql.pyx", line 1683, in _mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
_mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (208, b"Invalid object name 'users'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Version details:

- SQL Server --> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2) (KB3171021) - 12.0.5000.0
- Airflow --> Tried 1.10.5 & latest 1.10.9
- Python --> 3.6

Comment: Please share any information about your issue, logs, errors, configuration, etc.

Comment: @joeb - I have added the details, please check